# Why is the while loop unable to break?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

```
answer = 5
guess = int(input('Please make a wild number guess: '))
count = 1

while guess != answer:
    count += 1
    int(input('wrong. Please make another guess: '))
    print(f"this is your {count} attempt") 

    if guess == answer:
        break
        print('Correct!!!')
```

i didn't get the **answer** i expected after i typed 5. i am still stucked in the while loop after typing the correct answer.

wrong. Please make another guess: 5
this is your 6 attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Soulfly mentioned, you need to update `guess`.

Also, I suggest changing:

```
 if guess == answer:
        break
        print('Correct!!!')
```

to

```
 if guess == answer:
        print('Correct!!!')
        break
```

So the loop won't break before outputting the print statment.

Answer (score 3):

because you are not updating the value of "guess" inside your while loop, change it to be

```
guess = int(input('wrong. Please make another guess: '))
```

Comment: oh my god. thanks a lot. can't believe i make a silly mistake like this.

Comment: Anytime :) remember to mark the correct answer!